# How to create a page that's split diagonally and the two halves are clickable links

Tags: css, html, html5-canvas

I need to create a landing page that's split diagonally.
Something like this

[image]

I need both areas of the page to be clickable and, in the best possible scenario, everything should adapt dinamically to the monitor of the user so that the monitor is always split in half.

How could i do it?Should i use canvas?Any advice is welcome, also on possible fallbacks if i use canvas.

Comment: I have done this, I will dig the snippet after few hours. But I need a bounty for this He He

Comment: How should the page be splitted?, And is different colors neccessary?

Comment: @Starx it should be splitted diagonally, one part black and one white. As i said, it should split the page in two

Comment: And you dont care, what is below these white and black area, just clickable links right?

Comment: @Starx yes that's more or less it!

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti the whole area is a perfect square or it could be a rectangle? what if you resize the browser window?

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan tit's the browser windows at full screen, possibly resolution indipendent, but if the window is resized nothing should happen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be realized in several ways:

1) on modern browsers in pure CSS using `clip-path`

> [Codepen Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dMNzYG)

**HTML**

```
<div>
   <a href="#1"></a>
   <a href="#2"></a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
a { 
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}

a:first-child {
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0 100vh, 100% 100vh);
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0 100vh, 100% 100vh);
    background: #d6d6d6;
}

a:last-child {
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100vh);
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100vh);
    background: #212121;
}
```

---

2) On less recent browsers, involving only a bit of javascript and `2D Transformation`

> [Codepen Demo](http://codepen.io/fcalderan/pen/NPNGQw)

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <section><a href="#1"></a></section>
    <section><a href="#2"></a></section>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body, div{ height: 100%; width: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0; }
div { overflow : hidden; position: relative;  }

section { 
    position      : absolute;
    top           : -100%;
    height        : 500vw;
    width         : 500vh;
    background    : #ccc; 
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform-origin: 0 0;
}

section + section {
    background    : #333;    
    top           : 0%;
}

section a { display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; cursor: pointer; }
```

**Js/jQuery**:

```
$(function() {

   $(window).on('resize', function() {
       var h = $(document).height(),
           w = $(document).width(); 

      /*  Math.atan() function returns the arctangent (in radians) 
       *  of a number and 1 rad ~= 57.29577 deg 
       */
       var angle = Math.atan(h/w) * 57.29577;
       var rotateProperty = "rotate(" + angle + "deg)";

       $('section').css({
          "-webkit-transform": rotateProperty,
          "-moz-transform": rotateProperty,
          "transform": rotateProperty
       });

   })
   .triggerHandler('resize');
});
```

Comment: @NicolasPeluchetti after 4 years could I change my answer so as to not involve javascript?

Comment: vh and vw are not supported  on android < 4.4 and browsers like opera. any workaround for that ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are talking about HTML you can use an image with an image map

[Image map example with triangle](http://www.elated.com/articles/creating-image-maps/)

Comment: OP is talking about splitting the page, not the image.

Comment: I'm talking about splitting the page, an image with a map would be the last fallback

Comment: @Starx: Physically there's only one image with 2 colors. The image map is used to have 2 clickable area's

Comment: @barts, First, you didn't provide an answer, you gave a RTFM suggestion, and next page and image are two different things, It might be the last resort as he said.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old topic, but I was looking for a solution myself and ended up figuring out that SVG is the real, cross-browser answer. You can have links directly in the SVG.

[Also on CodePen](https://codepen.io/captainvascular/pen/MrPyRd)

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
svg {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
svg > a:first-child > path {
  cursor: pointer;
  fill: #ccc;
}
svg > a:last-child > path {
  cursor: pointer;
  fill: #999;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <a href="#1"><path d="M 0 0 L 100 100 L 100 0 z"></path></a>
    <a href="#2"><path d="M 100 100 L 0 100 L 0 0 z"></path></a>
  </svg>
</div>
```

This solution works in modern browsers, Edge, and IE11. I didn't test any older browsers.

For some reason Chrome will not show the "pointer" cursor unless it is specifically added to the path CSS.